# PHP negative time calculation

Tags: php, time, subtraction

If I add 1 hour and 35 minutes in PHP and subtract 4 hours, I get a remaining time of -3 hours and 30 minutes.

But correct would be -2 hours and 30 minutes. Where’s the mistake?

```
    $minutes = null;
    while ($z = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $minutes += $z['minutes'];
    }

   
    if ($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':user' => $user
        ));
        $negativeTime = null;
        while ($z = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $negativeTime += $z['minutes'];
        }
    }
    $minutes = $minutes - $negativeTime;

    echo (floor($minutes / 60)) . " hours and " . ($minutes - floor($minutes / 60) * 60) . " minutes";
```

Comment: Please post a [mre]. The SQL queries aren't needed, just post the actual values of `$minutes` and `$negativeTime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$minutes - floor($minutes/60)` is positive. So what you're getting is -3 hours *plus* 30 minutes, which is -2:30.

You need to treat positive and negative values of `$minutes` differently, so that both the hours and minutes are the distance from zero. Use the `abs()` function to convert the time to positive, perform the calculation, then show the hours as negative if the original value of `$minutes` was negative.

```
$sign = $minutes < 0 ? '-' : '';
$minutes = abs($minutes);
$hours = floor($minutes / 60);
$minutes = $minutes % 60;

echo "$sign$hours hours and $minutes minutes";
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/1em0M3)

Comment: Would I get with your soulution -2:30 instead of -3:30?

Comment: Try it and see!

Comment: Mhm but then I won't get negative Time? I want to get negative time. -3:30 is wrong. -2:30 would be correct.

Comment: Why won't you get negative time? Don't you see `$sign` in the output?

Comment: No, I don't get -2:30

Comment: It works for me: https://ideone.com/1em0M3

Comment: What is your value of `$minutes`? I get `-2:30` with `$minutes = -150;`

Comment: I get +1:30. I think $negativeTime is not subtracted from $minutes.

Comment: What are your values of `$minutes` and `$negativeTime` before you combine them?

Comment: variable $minutes is 90

Comment: And what is `$negativeTime`?

Comment: $negativeTime is 240

Comment: So after you do `$minutes = $minutes - $negativeTime`, it should be `$minutes = -150`.

Comment: Yep, it will be: https://ideone.com/YuQ0Sx :-)

Comment: You are the best! It works! Thank you!